# Jquery select option val

Tags: javascript, jquery, selected

im working in a project that i will have about 10 select boxes with same class and i want to check if ALL of selected boxes are selected with jquery. Here is my html code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="analysis.php" method="post" id="mobileform" >
<select class="form-control selectx" name="phone1">
    <option value="" selected>Select phone</option>
    <option value="iphone6" selected>Iphone 6</option>
    <option value="galaxys5" selected>Galaxy S5</option>
</select>            
<select class="form-control selectx" name="phone2">
    <option value="" selected>Select phone</option>
    <option value="iphone6" selected>Iphone 6</option>
    <option value="galaxys5" selected>Galaxy S5</option>
</select>       
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit"> Submit !</button><br>
```

And here is my jquery

```
                            $(document).ready(function() {
                            $('form').submit(function(event) {
                                $(".selectx option:selected").each(function()
                                {
                                    if($(this).val() === "") {
                                    $('#selecterror').fadeIn(300);
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                }else{
                                    $('#selecterror').hide();
                                    }
                                });
                              });
                        });
```

But it doesnt work if you example in 1st selectbox with name phone1 you dont select anything and in selectbox with name phone2 you select a phone.

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

In your case, both select options have to be empty for the validation. You can use `.filter` to see if any of the select options is empty:

```
 $('form').submit(function(event) {
      var empty = $(".selectx option:selected").filter(
            function() {
                return $(this).val() == "";
             });

      if(empty.length) {
              $('#selecterror').fadeIn(300);
              event.preventDefault();
      }else{
              $('#selecterror').hide();
      }

  });
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/hptqq1tL/